# Raspberry hostname.local unable to resolve in MacBook Pro with Maverik

Tags: networking, ssh

I setup my raspberry with hostname but I cannot reach with SSH or WEB browser by my MacBookPro (running under maverick). If i try by WIN 7 everything works!

On raspberry I setup avahi.

Running avahi-browse --all

- eth0 IPv4 gmvpi Remote Disk Management local
- eth0 IPv4 gmvpi SSH Remote Terminal local
- eth0 IPv4 gmvpi _device-info._tcp local
- eth0 IPv4 gmvpi Apple File Sharing local
- eth0 IPv4 gmvpi [b8:27:eb:ea:80:9f] Workstation local
  Running avahi-resolve --address 192.168.1.20

192.168.1.20    gmvpi.local
so if i try ssh pi@gmvpi.local

ssh: Could not resolve hostname gmvpi.local: nodename nor servname provided, or not known and of course nor ping

if I address directly the IP 192.168.1.20 everyting works.
in finder the pi is present with gmvpi, so the problem should be just in resolving name

Any suggestion?

thank you for attention

Comment: You have avahi-daemon running on the Pi?

Answer (score 1):

I installed `netatalk` on my Pi rather than `avahi` which did not seem to be available from the repositories, but both offer the same zero-conf facilities.

Initially I had some difficulties, my Pi would appear in Finder, but I could not connect.
I forced connection with `afp://IPaddress`, and can now connect reliably in Finder.

I have always connected to the Pi with `ssh pi@10.1.1.10` and just tried `ssh pi@BinniePi.local`
I received an error

```
The authenticity of host 'binniepi.local (10.1.1.10)' can't be established
```

I persisted, following prompts, and now both Finder and ssh can connect.

There is a new entry in ~/.ssh/known_hosts

PS I generated a RSA key on my Mac (years ago), and installed the public key on the Pi in

```
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: in my case the message is:" Could not resolve hostname gmvpi.local: nodename nor servname provided " so I thinks it's a problem of name resolution

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM SOLVED!!

In my macbook pro system preference --> Network --> Advanced --> DNS I changed in domain from "Workgroup" to "local" now i can ping Raspberry as pi@gmvpi.workgroup and

http://gmvpi.workgroup it's ok also!! also in ftp as gmvpi.workgroup it's ok